# Sort zipped lists alphabetically and also sort the second one based on another list**Double sorting**

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

So I have these three lists,

```
 last_names= ["B","A","A","A","B","G","G"]
 courses = [ 'Comp','Chem','Phys', 'Comp', 'Chem', 'Phys', 'Chem']
 grades = [3,2,3,3,2,1,3]
```

So "last_names" should be sorted alphabetically and then "courses" should be sorted based  on this list:

```
 ['Math','Chem','Comp','Phys']
```

All this should happen while the elements in the three list should be reordered the same way so we keep all three of them connected to one another.

So results should look like this:

```
 last_names= ["A","A","A","B","B","G","G"]
 courses = [ 'Chem','Comp','Phys', 'Chem', 'Comp', 'Chem', 'Phys']
 grades = [2,3,3,2,3,3,1]
```

I tried to make a dictionary and sort them in there but it got complicated and I could not figure out a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the triplets, sort them by last names and course and then get the elements back.
I'm using a dictionary to associate the course with the index so that we can look for the index in constant time instead of using `courses_order.index()`.

```
>>> courses_order = ['Math','Chem','Comp','Phys']
>>> courses_idx = {el:idx for idx, el in enumerate(courses_order)}
>>> t = sorted(zip(last_names, courses, grades), key=lambda x:(x[0],courses_idx[x[1]]))
>>> last_names, courses, grades = zip(*t)
>>> last_names
('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'G', 'G')
>>> courses
('Chem', 'Comp', 'Phys', 'Chem', 'Comp', 'Chem', 'Phys')
>>> grades
(2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip and enumerate for that like

```
courses_sort = ['Math','Chem','Comp','Phys']
for i, v in enumerate(sorted(zip(last_names, courses, grades), key=lambda x: x[0]+ str(courses_sort.index(x[1])))):
    last_names[i], courses[i], grades[i] = v[0], v[1], v[2]
```

This code will concat values in the same index from the three lists and then will sort them by the last_names list.
Output

```
last_names = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'G', 'G']
courses = ['Chem', 'Comp', 'Phys', 'Chem', 'Comp', 'Chem', 'Phys']
grades = [2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a combination of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip),[`*(unpacking)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get your output

```
last_names,courses,grades = [list(tup) for tup in zip(*sorted(zip(last_names,courses,grades)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

have try numpy or pandas?
if using numpy look like:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.sort(np.array([last_names,courses,grades]))
```

or using pandas look like:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'lastnames':last_names,'courses':courses,'grades':grades})
data.sort_values(by=['lastnames'],inplace=True)
```

if You work with xlsx or csv file, better using pandas

Comment: Thanks! I have done that but the problem is in the second step where I have to the course based on the specific list I mentioned above so basically it's a double sorting